# Emailing a Hard Drive Disk Space Alert Using Powershell

Tags: email, powershell

I've been browsing the web trying to find a way if possible to email a low disk space alert from a Gmail account to a shared mail box using power shell but Im struggling with a query I've managed to piece together.

```
$EmailFrom =  "FromEmail@Gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "ToEmail@Gmail.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password"); 
$Computers = "Local Computer"
$Subject = "Disk Space Storage Report" 
$Body = "This report was generated because the drive(s) listed below have less than $thresholdspace % free space. Drives above this threshold will not be listed." 

[decimal]$thresholdspace = 50

$tableFragment = Get-WMIObject  -ComputerName $computers Win32_LogicalDisk `
| select __SERVER, DriveType, VolumeName, Name, @{n='Size (Gb)' ;e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.size/1gb)}},@{n='FreeSpace (Gb)';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.freespace/1gb)}}, @{n='PercentFree';e={"{0:n2}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size*100)}} `
| Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} `
| ConvertTo-HTML -fragment

$regexsubject = $Body
$regex = [regex] '(?im)<td>'

if ($regex.IsMatch($regexsubject)) {$smtpclinet.send($fromemail, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)}
```

Script runs but nothing happens, any help would be fantastic!!!

Comment: Apply divide and conquer tactic to the debugging. Break the script in pieces and find out which part fails. Does the WMI query report good results? Can you send arbitary mail via Gmail?

Comment: There are typo's which won't help `smtpclinet`. Why not use `Send-MailMessage`? Anyway, you're getting nothing because you never merge `$tableFragment` into `$Body`. If `$Body` does not contain an HTML table  with table data the mail is never sent.

Comment: Another problem  for you. `$Body` is built incorporating a `$thresholdspace` variable. The `$thesholdspace` variable is not set until after `$Body` has already used the value.

Comment: @vonPryz Yes i have managed to send emails straight from powershell to another mailbox before i chopped and put it all back together. I have been trying that technique already but no luck.

Comment: @ChrisDent - I was previously using Send-mailmessage but i was getting all sorts of errors so i switched. I've fixed my spelling ( thanks for spotting that). Im not very knowledged in powershell to begin with. Can you give an example of how it should be written ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version would be longer because I'd have made a substitute for Send-MailMessage such that swapping between mine and Send-MailMessage is trivial.

This is one possible way of doing it. There are good uses for the Fragment parameter on ConvertTo-Html, but not much of a justification to do so here.

This is a script and expected to be a .ps1 file. Mandatory things I don't really want to hard-code beyond a default are set in the param block.

```
param(
    [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

    [Decimal]$Theshold = 0.5,

    [PSCredential]$Credential = (Get-Credential)
)

#
# Supporting functions
#

# This function acts in much the same way as Send-MailMessage.
function Send-SmtpMessage {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [String[]]$To,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
        [String]$Subject,

        [String]$Body,

        [Switch]$BodyAsHtml,

        [String]$SmtpServer = $PSEmailServer,

        [Int32]$Port,

        [Switch]$UseSSL,

        [PSCredential]$Credential,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]$From
    )

    if ([String]::IsNullOrEmtpy($_)) {
        # I'd use $pscmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError for this normally
        throw 'A value must be provided for SmtpServer'
    }

    # Create a mail message
    $mailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    # Email address formatting si validated by this, allowing failure to kill the command
    try {
        foreach ($recipient in $To) {
            $mailMessage.To.Add($To)
        }
        $mailMessage.From = $From
    } catch {
        $pscmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
    $mailMessage.Subject = $Subject

    $mailMessage.Body = $Body
    if ($BodyAsHtml) {
        $mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
    }

    try {
        $smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, $Port)
        if ($UseSSL) {
            $smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true
        }
        if ($psboundparameters.ContainsKey('Credential')) {
            $smtpClient.Credentials = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential()
        }

        $smtpClient.Send($mailMessage)
    } catch {
        # Return errors as non-terminating
        Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
    }
}

#
# Main
#

# This is inserted before the table generated by the script
$PreContent = 'This report was generated because the drive(s) listed below have less than {0} free space. Drives above this threshold will not be listed.' -f ('{0:P2}' -f $Threshold) 

# This is a result counter, it'll be incremented for each result which passes the threshold
$i = 0
# Generate the message body. There's not as much error control around WMI as I'd normally like.
$Body = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType=3' -ComputerName $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
    # PSCustomObject requires PS 3 or greater.
    # Using Math.Round below means we can still perform numeric comparisons
    # Percent free remains as a decimal until the end. Programs like Excel expect percentages as a decimal (0 to 1).
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName     = $_.__SERVER
        DriveType        = $_.DriveType
        VolumeName       = $_.VolumeName
        Name             = $_.Name
        'Size (GB)'      = [Math]::Round(($_.Size / 1GB), 2)
        'FreeSpace (GB)' = [Math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace / 1GB), 2)
        PercentFree      = [Math]::Round(($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size), 2)
    }
} | Where-Object {
    if ($_.PercentFree -lt $Threshold) {
        $true
        $i++
    }
} | ForEach-Object {
    # Make Percentage friendly. P2 adds % for us.
    $_.PercentFree = '{0:P2}' -f $_.PercentFree

    $_
} | ConvertTo-Html -PreContent $PreContent | Out-String

# If there's one or more warning to send.
if ($i -gt 0) {
    $params = @{
        To         = "ToEmail@Gmail.com"
        From       = "FromEmail@Gmail.com"
        Subject    = "Disk Space Storage Report"
        Body       = $Body
        SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
        Port       = 587
        UseSsl     = $true
        Credential = $Credential
    }
    Send-SmtpMessage @params
}
```